# Facebook Marketing API - Creating an Ad in development mode

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api, facebook-python-business-sdk

I'm implementing an application using Facebook Marketing API's SDK ([python](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-python-business-sdk://)), I'm a newbie to this, yet I read the documentation and I was able to create campaigns, and ad sets. But not for ad creatives. The error was that my app is in dev mode and I need to switch it to be public.

```
Status:  400
  Response:
    {
      "error": {
        "message": "Invalid parameter",
        "type": "OAuthException",
        "code": 100,
        "error_subcode": 1885183,
        "is_transient": false,
        "error_user_title": "Ads creative post was created by an app that is in development mode",
        "error_user_msg": "Ads creative post was created by an app that is in development mode. It must be in public to create this ad.",
        "fbtrace_id": "Dxgr83ugqSu"
      }
    }
```

Once I did, another error occurred stating that an extended permission should be granted:

```
Status:  403
 Response:
   {
     “error”: {
       “message”: “(#294) Managing advertisements requires an access token with the extended permission for ads_management”,
       “type”: “OAuthException”,
       “code”: 294,
       “fbtrace_id”: “HZ8N55VciZg”
     }
   }
```

What I did understand is that I need to submit my app for review before trying to push the ad. However, I was wondering if it is possible by anyway to push an ad without doing so? for the sake of testing my script?

Note: it is the same case for sandbox mode.

apologize if this sound like a naive question.

Comment: Same as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54345229/3679900) & [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51926462/3679900)

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59835822/3679900) too