# Not able to create ad creative using Facebook graph api

Tags: facebook-marketing-api, facebook-insights

I'm making a Facebook ads application with Marketing API. I'd create an ad Sandbox account and using its access token, I've successfully created Campaign, AdSet and upload some pictures for making ads. Now from past few days, I'm trying to create  Ad Creative through API but every time it showing error "Ads creative post was created by an app that is in development mode". Creation of Campaign and Adset working fine with API but AdCreation showing error. Without AdCreation, I'm not able to create Ads. Please help me out.

I'm trying to fetch Insights of ads from API in development mode without buying any ads and SANDBOX seems the only way to do it but unfortunately, it's not working.

[image]

Comment: Same as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53994519/3679900) & [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51926462/3679900)

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59835822/3679900) too

Answer (score 0):

you gotta get your app approved of the ads_management permissions under Marketing API in order to create... creatives. It is a hassle, but

Comment: I don't believe that is required (since otherwise it defies the purpose of `Sandbox` mode)