# Error while creating adcreatives using facebook marketing API in sandbox account

Tags: facebook-marketing-api

I am trying to create dynamic Facebook ads using marketing API in the sandbox account. I am following [this document](https://github.com/keboola/ex-facebook-graph-api/wiki/Sandbox-Ad-Account-Testing-Environment?fbclid=IwAR1F-k5cnwoptVbRYSrLqtxTg91UsMnCUjEEAqMOOvGYTBJPryukeDllePo).
Now I am unable to create adcreatives. I am getting this error "Ads creative post was created by an app that is in development mode. It must be in public to create this ad.".

Here is my code :
`try {
  $response = $fb->post(
    '/act_<SANDBOX_ACCOUNT_ID>/adcreatives',
    array (
      'name' => 'Sample Creative',
      'object_story_spec' => '{ "link_data": { "image_hash": "5d9cdde5f43dffdec3165e06c1bc3f21", "link": "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t45.1600-4/82783061_120330000035086911_1622348699776581632_n.png?_nc_cat=102&_nc_ohc=np_jpbh2yzIAX8TX6Yt&_nc_ht=scontent.xx&oh=d3c2d425ab9d87154aad9f376eabe8fe&oe=5EC6F7EF", "message": "try it out"     },    "page_id": "493348931012140"}'
    ),
    '{access-token}'
  );
}`

Comment: Share your code

Comment: 3rd duplicate (4th question overall describing same issue); Same as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53994519/3679900), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54345229/3679900) & [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51926462/3679900)